# Is it better to save references to HTML elements for reuse?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it recommend to save references to HTML elements if you continuously write something into a HTML Tag with JavaScript or does it not make a big difference?  If you save the reference into a variable or if you call it always directly, for example:

```js
document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "$"+Setting.Selection[0].price;
```

```html
<p id="price"></p>
```

This above example show how I do it now and I want to know if I can do it another way better with saving the reference anywhere, I want to optimize my code to use less memory.

Comment: Well `.getElementById()` is a function call. It's generally really fast in modern browsers, but it's inarguably faster to avoid making a function call than to make one unnecessarily.

Comment: Also less code to write each time and variable names can sometimes be more intuitive  than the elements they reference

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable such as this, an a place that can be accessed wherever it is needed:

```
var priceDiv = document.getElementById("price");
```

Then when you want to make changes you do so like this:

```
priceDiv.innerHTML = //whatever...
```

Comment: Should i make the Variable global or in a function where i use it? Because i did hear that global variables also take more RAM useage or? I want to optimize my code to make less RAM useage as possible.

Comment: Probably not a global function. It really depends on the structure of your code. Ar you using Webforms? MVC? Web API? How many times is the variable accessed in each method? Are you declaring all you JavaScript methods in one place, or on separate pages? The answer will vary depending on your setup. If you post examples of your code I can give you a better answer.

Comment: i use it most time in the same page where the html and javascript code is written and i have often in my code functions which are getting called every few seconds again and again with setInterval() or setTimeout().

Comment: In that case declare the variable in a place that can be accessed by all the methods on that page. That way it will only be created once and then accessed when it is needed.

Comment: Alex, do you know if its better to create a Javascript Object as global variable or in a function? I mean because of memory useage, which method use less memory, if you create it global i think it will be created only one time, but i dont know if the Object save the values forever or if he make the object bigger and bigger with time. If you create it into a function i think it will be created always again and again, but his values from before will be delte. I am trying to find out currently which way use less memory.

Comment: You probably do not need to worry about such a small optimisation, unless the object is going to grow too large - which in this case I do not think will happen. With regard to the scope of the variable, it should not be a global variable, but should be declared on the page where the HTML element is declared, and on the same level as the method declaration. If you post an example of your page I will show you where to declare the variable

Comment: If you can take a look at this post from me, that would be nice from you, because that are questions abouth the same thinks which i am not sure abouth how to code better for smaller memory useage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388066/javascript-code-and-ram-memory-useage-questions